# Shopify Cart - Dynamic Custom Field Snippet Repeating

Tags: shopify, cart, liquid, shopping-cart

I've successfully injected a custom cart field if item.product.tags matches a certain condition. However, this field repeats for every instance of the line_item. How can I control/limit the returned field to display once if there's multiple items that match the condition?

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% if item.product.tags contains "trunkbox" %}
    <label for="po_number">PO Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="attributes[PO Number]" required class="required" id="po_number" value="{{ cart.attributes['PO Number'] }}" />
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

May You are asking for a loop break to insert your custom input only once?

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% if item.product.tags contains "trunkbox" %}
    <label for="po_number">PO Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="attributes[PO Number]" required class="required" id="po_number" value="{{ cart.attributes['PO Number'] }}" />

    {% break %}

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```